# can't bring up task manager applications tab on windows 7

Tags: task-manager

On an old Dell D810 running a clean W7 I am unable to bring up Task Manager with all its options.

Normally I would expect:
File Options View Help and tabs with something like Applications on one of the tabs. What I need to do is to see what tasks are running and kill ones I don't want.

All I get is 3 windows: (1) Wireless Network Connection 2, (2) Bluetooth Network Connection 2, (3) Local Area Connection

The Windows system32 folder contains exactly the same taskmgr.exe (date/time stamp, bytes of length) as on an M90 which correctly shows what is expected.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Quick way to Task Manager on any Windows since at least XP is Ctrl/Shift/Esc. Does that work?

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-windows-task-manager-with-missing-tabs-and-menu/

Comment: You are seeing the Networking tab of the Windows Task Manager with the standard menu and tabs hidden. As explained in the answer to this question below, double click the Task Manager to "undhide" those options.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on one of the windows mentioned. That will return to the tabbed format. Double click on that and it will go back to the "no tabs" format.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain that the window OP is seeing the the Networking tab in Windows Task Manager (sans standard menu/tabs).

Comment: Note, to see this double click option use the Performance tab.